# findAndModify or findOneAndUpdate - "is not a function"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

First of all, which one is best?
`findAndModify` or `findOneAndUpdate` or `findByIdAndUpdate`?

In my case I got a table like this:

**seqkeys**

```
{ 
    "_id" : "invoice", 
    "seq" : NumberInt(1)
},
{ 
    "_id" : "receipt", 
    "seq" : NumberInt(1)
}
```

And I want to find the seq number for invoice, add 1 and save. *(and then use that number to save the real invoice record in the invoice table)*

But I cant get this to work, I constantly get

```
TypeError: seqkeysTable.findAndModify is not a function
```

So here is my model:

```
var mongoose      = require('mongoose');
var Schema        = mongoose.Schema;
var seqkeysSchema = new Schema({
    _id:                String,     // Table Name
    seq:                Number      // Sequence Number
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('seqkeysModel', seqkeysSchema,'seqkeys');
```

And here is my `findkey` nodejs function....

```
var seqkeysModel = require('../../models/seqkeysModel');
var seqkeysTable = mongoose.model('seqkeysModel');
var findKey = function(tableName) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    seqkeysTable.findAndModify(
        { "_id": tableName },
        { $inc: {"seq":1} },
        { new: true }
    ,function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            reject(new Error('findKey ERROR : ' + err));
            return;
        } else {
            resolve(data.seq);
        };
    });
})};
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Mongoose has `findOneAndUpdate` (equivalent of mongoBD [findAndModify](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/). MongoDB also introduced [findOneAndUpdate](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/) in version >= 3.2) and `findByIdAndUpdate`. That's why `findAndModify` won't work with Mongoose.

As to which one is better, in [findOneAndUpdate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate) you can pass query object containing multiple fields while [findByIdAndUpdate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate) only takes id as the first parameter.

Comment: Thanks Talha - I will try findByIdAndUpdate and see if it will work.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/search/?query=findByIdAndUpdate
hahaha I guess they forgot to put that in their manual :-D

Comment: No they didn't :) findByIdAndUpdate is not part of mongoDB. it's Mongoose's.

Answer (score 5):

`findAndModify` is a function of MongoDB, That's why that doesn't work with Mongoose.

Both `findOneAndUpdate` and `findByIdAndUpdate` works well with Mongoose, perhaps if you wish to use _id to search in the database then go for `findByIdAndUpdate` else if you are using a different field to search in the database then use `findOneAndUpdate`.

However, if you try to use `findAndModify` in MongoDB, you might get the following warning :

```
DeprecationWarning: collection.findAndModify is deprecated. Use findOneAndUpdate, findOneAndReplace or findOneAndDelete instead.
```

To eliminate this use the following in your code :

```
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
```

Just in case, difference between `findByIdAndUpdate` & `findOneAndUpdate` :

> findByIdAndUpdate(id, ...) is equivalent to findOneAndUpdate({ _id: id
> }, ...)

Comment: this answer is misleading, there is no such thing called findByIdAndUpdate in mongoDB. As mentioned in above answer by Talha, findByIdAndUpdate is from mongoose.

Comment: Did you misspell "MongoDB" as "MongoBD" here?